# Recursively display all children and grandchildren on page, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, recursion

I'm trying to display these records in a table with the top level records first and all children and grandchildren under them with a '-' , '--' etc.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it programmatically though, without just repeating myself.  This is what I have that displays the the top level and first child of each.

```
            - @staff_resources.top_level.each do |staff_resource|
              = render 'staff_resource', staff_resource: staff_resource, depth: 0
              - staff_resource.children.each do |staff_resource_child|
                - depth = 1
                = render 'staff_resource', staff_resource: staff_resource_child, depth: depth
```

````
  %td= "#{'-' * depth} #{staff_resource.name}"
  %td.icons.text-center.nowrap
    = link_to edit_admin_staff_resource_path(staff_resource), class: 'edit-icon' do
      = image_tag 'common/edit.svg'
    = link_to admin_staff_resource_path(staff_resource), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: 'delete-icon' do
      = image_tag 'common/delete.svg'```
````

Comment: If this can go to arbitrary depth, and your underlying database supports it, then the most efficient way to do this is to write a custom recursive cte: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-recursive-query/
The output table should include a `depth` column that you can use to tell how much to indent. If you've never done this before then write some practice queries first.

Comment: beautiful, thank you!  works perfect.